# What does 'MT' mean in Twitter?

Tags: twitter

I keep seeing 'MT' used in much the same way that 'RT' is frequently used.

What is the difference? Should I be using 'MT'?

Comment: You can also continue what you are doing... their practices are users' personal opinions (not official Twitter features). Staying clear of these abbreviations can ensure that users (like yourself) don't have to search somewhere to understand a simple 140 character message.

Comment: Simple google search: http://socialmediacertificate.net/2011/02/rt-mt-ht-via-the-importance-of-giving-credit-on-twitter/

Answer (score 35, accepted):

MT: Modified Tweet

The user edited the original tweet in some way to stay within the 140 character limit.

RT: Retweet

The user rebroadcasted the original tweet without changing or editing it.

You should continue using RT and use MT only in exceptional cases where you know the meaning of the original tweet may get lost when trying to get the message under 140 characters.

Comment: And furthermore, instead of doing a textual RT, it's better to use the retweet button. That will be guaranteed to fit within the 140-character limit, and will also provide proper attribution and make it easier to follow any RT or conversational chain it was part of.

Comment: @fluffy while I totally agree sometimes adding something to the tweet gives context as to why you are retweeting it.

Answer (score 9):

It means *modified tweet*, which is a retweet with a slight modification of the original tweet.