# Why do some people start their tweets with a dot?

Tags: twitter

Nowadays in my Twitter feed I have started seeing Tweets with a preceding `.` (dot) in them. I don't know why they do so. [Here is](https://twitter.com/netmag/status/287156352944599040) such an example.

Why are they wasting their one character for `.`? Especially if they already have a limit of 140 characters?

Comment: MT if you wanted to know: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/21161/what-does-mt-mean-in-twitter

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you start a Tweet with "@username" then only that person and people following you and that person will see the Tweet.

If you want to be seen to be addressing a particular person then adding something before the "@username" is the simplest way to do it.

You could do something like:

> Did you know @username ...

or

> Hi, @username ....

but these would take up even more characters from the rest of the message. A single character takes up the least space and a dot is the least obtrusive.

It's all about bragging to your followers. You are saying "Look, I'm in a conversation with @username" :)

Comment: Can you tell me what does **MT** stands for?

Comment: @SantoshKumar - "Modified Tweet". Basically a RT (Re-Tweet) that you've edited in some way. Though that is a separate question.

Comment: Even celebrities are not immune - https://twitter.com/GeorgeTakei/status/287326367228518400